# Get files from specific folders in a directory in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have 4 folders in a directory. All of those folders contains some files. I want to list the file names only from the two folders.

```
C:\MainFolder\FolderOne\FileOne.txt
C:\MainFolder\FolderTwo\FileTwo.txt
C:\MainFolder\FolderThree\FileThree.txt
C:\MainFolder\FolderFour\FileFour.txt
```

I only want to list the files under FolderTwo and FolderThree.

If I use `-Recurse -Include "FolderNames"` it'll list only the folder names.

Comment: `Get-ChildItem 'C:\MainFolder\FolderTwo'; Get-ChildItem 'C:\MainFolder\FolderThree'`

Comment: It works, Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$source="c:\MainFolder" #location of starting directory
$files=@("*.txt", "*.doc") #if you want to include extensions add -include ($files) to get-ChildItem

Get-ChildItem -recurse ($source) -File | Where-Object {$_.PSParentPath -match "Two|Three"}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
get-childitem -recurse 'foldertwo','folderthree'
```

Comment: It's working with ` get-childitem -recurse 'C:\MainFolder\FolderTwo','C:\MainFolder\FolderThree' `

Answer (score 0):

Did it like this

```
$arrPath ='C:\MainFolder\FolderTwo','C:\MainFolder\FolderThree'

get-childitem -recurse $arrPath
```